# Unity5 Survival Shooter GameObject has been destroyed

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I'm following the [Survival Shooter Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/enemy-one?playlist=17144) on the Unity website, however, when I went to test if my 'Zombunny' was spawning correctly. It spawned fine, just as it should ... until I started shooting them , as soon as I killed my first enemy I got this error:

```
"SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh.
```

I've already tried re - baking my environment but that still didn't work.

Comment: Can we see some of your code? Namely, where `SetDestination()` is called, and how you're destroying the "Zombunny"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your enemy, even dead, wants to reach your player.

Are you sure you are destroying the enemy gameobject properly?
Also if you correctly drop the enemy's health to 0 or less it should not happen in the context of the tutorial unless you forgot to add this (before calling navigation):

```
        if(enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0 && playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)
```